# AWS Athena date sql query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

Below is the data in csv file in s3 bucket which I have used to build Athena database.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Wright | cricket | 25 |
| Steve | Adams | football | 30 |

I am able to run the query and get the data.

Now I am trying to fetch date of birth based on age column. Is it possible to generate date of birth from age column like current date - age (column) and print only the date of birth?

I tried below query but not sure whether it is correct way

```
select (current_date - interval age day) from table_name;
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: You can't transform age in years into full birth date for obvious reason - you can get only the year of birth.

Comment: You may get year of birth iff age in csv file is calculated based on today's date. Otherwise, you'll endup with wrong year of birth in edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [date_add](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/datetime.html#date_add) function, like this:

```
SELECT date_add('year', -age, current_date) FROM table_name
```

I.e. subtract `age` number of `'year'`(s) from the `current date`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will ty this